Flatten the bottom of a curved object
I am beginner in blender. Firstly, I made a circle and then changed its diameters differently to make an ellipse. After that, I created the following shape by pressing E button and change its Z dimension (fig a). I want to flatten the bottom of the object as shown below (figb). To do this, I selected vertices and faces separately (fig c, e ), then pressed S Y 0. But the result was figures d and f. can you help me?
thanks a lot


That seems fine, but there seems to be a problem with the axis settings. If the object is rotated, the directional axis might be different. Please share the blender file of the object and we will inspect it. Upload the file here. Thanks.
https://blend-exchange.com/

It is not very clear from your screenshot how the geometry of your object actually looks like. First of all I assume you made the ellipsoid by scaling a circle slightly on the Y axis in Object Mode. Then you probably have not applied the scale. Do that by pressing Ctrl+A > Apply > Scale.
Then press Tab to go into Edit Mode. I further assume you have made a mesh circle consisting of vertices, not a Bézier circle. Make sure that the Transform Pivot Point is set to Active Element and Proportional Editing is enabled. I have used the Sharp falloff, but you can switch to others that might work better.

Then select so many vertices at the bottom as wide as you want the flat side to the left and right. Make sure the vertex at the bottom center is the active one by either selecting it last if you select them individually with Shift + left-clicking or by clicking it first and then selecting the others with box or circle select. Whatever you do, it should be marked different than the others.

Now hit S Y 0 to scale the vertices in Y direction to 0 to get a flat line. A circle appears to show you the influence radius of the Proportional Editing. Use the scroll wheel of your mouse to adjust the size until you are satisfied with the result.

Maybe you can additionally adjust the position on the Y axis by moving the selecting vertices with pressing G Y, again adjusting the influence radius for a better result.

But just for clarification: this is only to get you the result shown in the screenshots. Since you did not tell what your actual goal is with this shape there might be much better solutions in regard to how you keep going on from here. For example, it looks like it should be the bottom of a vase or something, but it is not even the bottom of the object, only of the screen. You're looking at it top down right down, so it is actually the front of the object that is flattened.

Thank you for your guidance. I did the steps you mentioned. But when I press S Y 0, its result is different. how can I share the figure of my results here?

I think it would be best to share your Blend file here so that we can see exactly what your object looks like.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. You can also edit your question and add extra images and text into it. (You can't add images into comments here.)

@aseman You could edit your question to give us more information. Like shwoing the whole interface so we can see what kind of object you have there etc. So far my answer is completely guesswork based on assumption what you might have done. For example I said in the beginning I assume you have made a mesh circle, not Bézier circle (a curve object), because then it will not really work with my method.

@aseman Of course your trial could not work. You do not have to do all steps literally like I did them but adjust them to your scene. Your question first showed a flat side in Y direction - that's why I told you to scale to 0 on Y based on your question. Your new images show that you selected faces in X direction. Of course you then have to scale to 0 in X direction, not Y!
